In app purchases for iOS app using flutter
I am setting up in app purchase for iOS app with flutter, I am using in_app_purchase package, I have created my product in App Store Connect in app purchase section and now my product in ready to submit status , when I am trying to get my product details list list I empty , I am currently trying in iOS simulator .Should it works on simulator(getting available products)?

Yes, you can get available products in iOS simulator by using InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails(ids)



Is there any thoughts why I am getting empty list then ?I am pretty sure that I am using right ids, maybe it is because my products in ready to submit status ?

Can you go to Agreements, Tax, and Banking on AppStore connect, do you have any active agreements?

There's on active regarding to Free apps and on in 'new' status regarding to paid app agreements , I guess I should submit paid agreements ?, I saw warning related to In app purchases.

Yes you need to fill in all the required information, paid app should have "active" status
